# Using paint method to create movement on form - not working

Tags: c#, winforms, paint

I am trying to draw a moving rectangle and circle on a form using the paint method.
A button should start the process. 2nd press should end the program.
The once variable is a global Boolean set to True on start.
X1 is a global int, set to 10 on start.
Up is a global Boolean, set to true on start.

Each iteration the X1 variable is increased until 100, going down to 10, endlessly.

I am observing two problems as following.

1. No movement of the drawing on the form
2. No control on the form once the program starts

Following is the code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)  
{  

    Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red,3);  
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x1, x1, x1, x1);  
    Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(x1+10, x1 + 10, x1 + 50, x1 + 50);  

    //Graphics g = e.Graphics;  
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();  
    g.DrawRectangle(red,rect);  
    g.DrawEllipse(red, circle);  

    red.Dispose();  
    g.Dispose();             
}  

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{            
    if (once)             
        once = false;              
    else  
        Environment.Exit(0);  

    while (true)  
    {  
        if (up )  
        {  
            x1 += 10;  
            if (x1 > 100)  
                up = false;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            x1 -= 10;  
            if (x1 <= 10)  
                up = true;  
        }  
        this.Invalidate();  
        Thread.Sleep(500);  
    }                      
}
```

Comment: There are **NO** forms in `WPF`, are you sure you are using WPF?

Comment: @XAMlMAX : It seems I was using the upf term without  knowing what it means. I was sure it means the forms in VS. Bad assumption. I don't use WPF. I use VS2017 with c#.

Comment: @YigalB - Then are you using WinForms? If so, please add the `winforms` tag.  This will attract the right users.

Comment: @Jay Buckman - done, thanks.

Comment: I wrote an article and a little library on doing WinForms animations a few years ago.. check it out. It explains how to do this.https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827808/Control-Animation-in-Winforms

Comment: I think the invalidate() is the non-working part. Did I wrongly use it?

Comment: Don't use `Graphics g = CreateGraphics();` especially in the Paint event: use the provided `e.Graphics` object. Don't use  `while (true)` in an event handler: this is not a Console application. Don't use `Thread.Sleep()`: you'll freeze the whole application. Use a Timer (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, here) or [ImageAnimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. I changed to e.Graphics. The while true is not in the handler: it is in the button's press handler, so activated only one. It is not intended to remain that way, just until I know how to draw movement, I removed the sleep totally, and still the form is freeze. I still think that there is a problem with the invalidate().

Comment: The problem is with the `while (true)` loop (which is inside an **event handler**: a `Button.Click` handler). You cannot use these loops in a graphic UI. You'll block it completely. As already mentioned, use a Timer or ImageAnimator.

Comment: @Jimi Fantastic ! for start I used timer for the first time, So easy! now the code looks nicer, no ugly while true statements, and it works just as expected. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this task using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, please see changes and comments:

```
private int x1 = 4;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
private bool once = true;
private bool up = false;
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // use e.Graphics
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x1, x1, x1, x1);
    Rectangle circle = new Rectangle(x1 + 10, x1 + 10, x1 + 50, x1 + 50);
    g.DrawRectangle(red, rect);
    g.DrawEllipse(red, circle);

    red.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (once)
    {
        once = false;
        Init();
    }
    else
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            timer = null;
        }
        // you can exit app...
         Application.Exit();
    }
}

private void Init()
{
    if (timer == null)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Tick += timer_tick;
    }

    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (up)
    {
        x1 += 10;
        if (x1 > 100)
            up = false;
    }
    else
    {
        x1 -= 10;
        if (x1 <= 10)
            up = true;
    }
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I just got the advice of using timer, did it and it is working. Highly appreciated !

Comment: @YigalB, Glad I could help! also, two more things that may come up later when using graphics: 1. you might want to reduce graphics flicker of the animation, please read that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls 2. you will need your shapes to be drawn smoothly - adding the line `g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;`  to `Form1_Paint()` method will do the job.

Comment: I understand, yet I am not sure if I capture the need at this time, as a newbie to this. The target is to draw a fixed background, made of horizontally and vertically lines, and a flickering small red circle that moves across according to input coordinates. The input coordinates come from external hardware via USB port. At this stage, I can read the data from the port correctly. Now I need to figure out how to design the drawing of the movement properly. I t seems I have the tools, but not yet clear design in mind.